# What is the Offset Corner Latitude and Longtitude?

Tags: geography, mapping, satellites, coordinate-system

[image: a part of offset corner]

I tried to understand about Offset Corner Latitude Point 1,2,3,4 and Offset Corner Longitude Point 1,2,3,4. But I couldn't understand what is it?

For example, I have the Frame center Latitude and Longitude. Can I calculate latitude and longitude of Frame Corners?

Does someone can explain me about Offset Corner Latitude and Longtitude?

sources: https://gwg.nga.mil/misb/docs/eg/EG0601.1.pdf

https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/19/MISB_Standard_0601.pdf

Comment: Can you please cite relevant parts of your sources, instead of linking to files which may be deleted?

Comment: did it. @Erik  .